# Which chess player has the most openings named after him?

Tags: opening, world-championship

I always thought it was interesting that chess players had openings named after them.  The game of chess has only been popular and organized for about 150 years, yet all the most popular openings and most of their sub-variations have already been named, many after players from the 19th or early 20th centuries.  In five hundred years, will all these basic openings still be named after Morphy, Steinitz, Capablanca, and Lasker?  But I digress.

Which player has had the most openings or opening variations named after him?  My guesses would be Botvinnik or Aljechin (Alekhine).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm way late to the party here, but would nevertheless like to mention the contributions of the seventh world champion (and my favorite player) [Vasily Smyslov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Smyslov). Here are some of his many eponymous systems and variations in major openings:

- The *Smyslov system* in the Grünfeld Defense: `1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 d5 4. Nf3 Bg7 5. Qb3 dxc4 6. Qxc4 O-O 7. e4`**`Bg4`**, intending to follow up with `... Nfd7` and `... Nb6`.
- The *Smyslov-Karpov variation* in the Caro-Kann Defense: `1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4`**`Nd7`**.
- The *Smyslov system* against the King's Indian Defense: `1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. Nf3 d6 5.`**`Bg5`**.
- The *Smyslov system* in the English Two Knights: `1. c4 e5 2. Nc3 Nf6 3. g3`**`Bb4`**.
- The *Smyslov defense* in the mainline closed Ruy Lopez: `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O Be7 6. Re1 b5 7. Bb3 O-O 8. c3 d6 9. h3`**`h6`**, intending to continue with `... Re8` and `... Bf8`, where the inclusion of `... h6` prevents a `Bg5` pin.
- Another *Smyslov defense* to the Ruy Lopez, featuring an early fianchetto: `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5`**`g6`**.
- The *Smyslov variation* in the Queen's Gambit Accepted: `1. d4 d5 2. c4 dxc4 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. e3`**`g6`**.
- The *Smyslov variation* in the Slav Defense: `1. d4 d5 2. c4 c6 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. Nc3 dxc4 5. a4`**`Na6 6. e4 Bg4`**.
- The *Reti-Smyslov variation* of the King's Indian Attack: `1. Nf3 Nf6 2. g3 g6 3.`**`b4`**.

Comment: You're the first person I have ever heard say that about Smyslov.

Comment: @TonyEnnis, it happened largely by accident. My first chess book was a Smyslov game collection.

Comment: I also love his games, and Botvinnik's.

Answer (score 15):

Nimzovitch.

1. NimzoIndian Defense: `1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 Bb4`
2. Nimzovitch Defense: `1.e4 Nc6`
3. Nimzovitch Attack: `1.Nf3 d5  2.b3` (1.b3 is the Nimzo-Larsen Attack)

**Nimzovitch Variations:**

4. Sicilian Defense: `1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nf6`
5. Queens Indian Defense: `1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 e6 3.Nf3 b6 4.g3 Ba6`
6. Falkbeer Counter-Gambit: `1.e4 e5 2.f4 d5 3.de5 c6`
7. Falkbeer Counter-Gambit: `1.e4 e5 2.f4 d5 3.de5 c6 4.e4 Bb5+ *`
8. Nimzovitch QP Defense: `1.d4 Nf6` (most sources attribute it to Bogoljubow)
9. Latvian Counter-Gambit: `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 f5 3. Nxe5 Qf6 4. d4 d6 5. Nc4 fxe4 6. Ne3`
10. Philidors Defense: `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 Nf6`
11. French Defense, Advance Var-Nimzovitch Var: `1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. e5 c5 4. Qg4`
12. French Defense, Nimzovitch (or Winawer) Var: `1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Bb4`
13. Four Kts Opening, Nimzovitch or Paulsen Var: `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bb5 Bb4 5. O-O O-O 6. Bxc6`
14. English Opening, Nimzovitch Var: `1.c4 e5 2.Nf3`
15. Benoni Defense, Nimzovitch or Kts Tour Var: `1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. d5 e6 4. Nc3 exd5 5. cxd5 d6 6. Nf3 g6 7. Nd2`
16. Caro-Kann Defense, Nimzovitch or Tartakower Var: `1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 de4 4.Ne4 Nf6 5.Nf6+ ef6`
17. Ruy Lopez, Steinitz Var - Nimzovitch Attack: `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 d6 4. d4 Bd7 5. Nc3 Nf6 6. Bxc6`
18. English Opening - Four Kts Var - Nimzovitch Var: `1. c4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. e4`
19. EO - Nimzo-English Opening: `1. c4 Nf6 2. Nc3 e6 3. Nf3 Bb4`

**Notes**: Simon Winawer played the "Winawer Variation" of the French Defense **once** in his entire career; why it's named after him instead of Nimzovitch who really popularized it is a mystery (to me at least). And no, Winawer **does not** deserve the credit for playing it first (if he even did that) many openings are named after the masters who hammered out the theory of them and/or made them popular. Ergo the "Advance Variation" of the French Defense should also be named after Nimzovitch!

SOURCES: "The Oxford Companion To Chess" by David Hooper & Kenneth Whyld, 1984; p 226
http://www.chessvideos.tv/chess-opening-database/search/Nimzovich-variation
http://www.365chess.com/eco/C62_Ruy_Lopez_old_Steinitz_defence_Nimzovich_attack

Answer (score 10):

Off the top of my head, there are a few players with multiple openings named after them:

## [Tarrasch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegbert_Tarrasch)

- Tarrasch Variation against the French Defense
- Tarrasch Opening against `d4` (with `...d5` and `...c5`)
- the Open Variation in the Ruy Lopez is technically the Tarrasch

## [Marshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Marshall_(chess_player))

- Marshall Gambit in the Slav
- Marshall Gambit in the Ruy Lopez
- Marshall Defense against the Queen's Gambit (`1. d4 d5 2. c4 Nf6?!`)
- Marshall Variation against the Sicilian (`1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 e6 3. d4 d5`)

## [Rubinstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiba_Rubinstein)

- Rubinstein Variation against the French (`...dxe4` and `Nxe4`)
- Rubinstein Variation against the Budapest (`1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e5 3. dxe4 Ng4 4. Bf4`)
- Rubinstein Variation against the Nimzo-Indian (white plays `e3`, `Nf3`, `Bd3`)
- Rubinstein Variation in the Four Knights
- Rubinstein Variation in the English (`1. c4 c5 2. Nc3 Nf6 3. g3 d5 4. cxd5 Nxd5 5. Bg2 Nc7`)

## [Steinitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Steinitz)

- Steinitz Defense against the Ruy Lopez (early `d6`)
- Steinitz Variation in the Petroff Defense (`3. d4`)
- the closed Sicilian is also called the Steinitz Variation
- Steinitz Gambit is `1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. f4`

Comment: Steinitz variation of Caro Kann defense 4...Nd7

Comment: @overtheboard I've always heard that referred to either as the Smyslov variation or the Karpov variation.  Incidentally, I play that as black fairly frequently when I want a low risk win against lower rated players.

Comment: Steinitz attack in the French: 1. e4 e6 2. e5

Answer (score 5):

Using [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_openings_named_after_people) as a guide, I can see that Frank Marshall, Carl Schlecter and Akiba Rubinstein have about 5 opening variations named after them.

Answer (score 0):

BUKAYEV, Yury V. (Букаев Ю.В.) is an inventor of many opening systems. Не isn't only a chess innovator, he is also innovator in chemistry and physics.

Comment: Can you give some examples of such openings? Otherwise what you have said isn't an answer. I haven't heard of any openings with "Bukayev" in the name.

Comment: For example, 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Nf6 4.Ng5 d5 5.exd5 Nd4 6.d6 Qxd6 7.Bxf7+ Ke7 8.Bb3 Nxb3 9.axb3 h6 10.Nf3 e4 11.Nh4! (the Nh4-Bukayev gambit) ...Kf7 12.f3!! (the source is chessproblem.my-free-games.com ).

Comment: how about gligoric. he's known as a theoretician